# Best approach to convert a non trivial function (CASE WHEN) into a lookup (decision) table?

Tags: database-design, functions, table, etl, case

Assume A, B, C etc are attribute values in the current rowset

Current function logic is similar to:

```
Case A = 'Y' then 
 Case B in (1,2,3,4,5) OR C in (3,4,5,6) then 'Sales'
 Case B in (99,98,102) OR D in (88,99) then 'IT'
 Case ( B in (104,105,105) AND C in (22,33,44) ) OR D in (27,28) then 'Accounts'
Else
 Case E in (1,2,3,4,5) OR C in (3,4,5,6) then 'HR'
 Case E in (99,98,102) OR D in (88,99) then 'Management'
 Case ( E in (104,105,105) AND C in (22,33,44) ) OR D in (27,28) then 'Security'
```

I think this means I need to create a table that looks like this:

| PRIORITY | OUTPUT | A val | B val | C val | D val | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sales | Y | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y | 2 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y | 3 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y | 4 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y | 5 |  |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y |  | 3 |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y |  | 4 |  |  |
| 1 | Sales | Y |  | 5 |  |  |
| 2 | IT | Y | 99 |  |  |  |
| 2 | IT | Y | 98 |  |  |  |
| 2 | IT | Y | 102 |  |  |  |
| 2 | IT | Y |  |  | 88 |  |
| 2 | IT | Y |  |  | 99 |  |
| ... | ... |  |  |  |  |  |

Then LEFT OUTER JOIN on each of the 3rd-to-Nth columns and return the OUTPUT with the lowest PRIORITY

Is that the best way to handle this?

How to structure if part of the function is WHEN X IS NOT IN (1,2,3)?

Comment: What is “priority” needed for? I can't see in the current `CASE` or further description any overlaps that would cause multiple matches to pick one from. Also it might help (as it could make a difference to what approached are suitable or not) to know what you are actually trying to model here, i.e. what A, B, C, ... represent and what sort and size of data you are filtering with this set of rules.

Comment: Because the actual rules are business confidential so I just created a mock dataset. In reality there could be multiple conflicting conditions. Apologies for not including some more realistic data in the example! I will update when I have a minute :D

Comment: If your schema & rules (not just your data) are _that_ sensitive then public help groups might not be the best place to find a advice. I'd suggest enlisting a contractor with relevant expertise who will sign an appropriate NDA (I'm not hinting “pay me” there - I have no time for a professional side-gig like that ATM!). Though sample data with fuller coverage of the likely combinations would help in either case.